# How to count the number of files in a directory using standard?

Tags: c++, c++17

The new standard expected for 2017 adds `std::filesystem`. Using it, how can I count the number of files (including sub-directories) in a directory?

I know we can do:

```
std::size_t number_of_files_in_directory(std::filesystem::path path)
{
    std::size_t number_of_files = 0u;
    for (auto const & file : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        ++number_of_files;
    }
    return number_of_files;
}
```

But that seems overkill. Does a simpler and faster way exist?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I do not think that a way to easily get amount of files in directory exist, but you can simplify your code by using `std::distance` instead of handwritten loop:

```
std::size_t number_of_files_in_directory(std::filesystem::path path)
{
    using std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    return std::distance(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator{});
}
```

You can get number of only actual files or apply any other filter by using `count_if` instead:

```
std::size_t number_of_files_in_directory(std::filesystem::path path)
{
    using std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    using fp = bool (*)( const std::filesystem::path&);
    return std::count_if(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator{}, (fp)std::filesystem::is_regular_file);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `difference_type` for [`directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator) is `std::ptrdiff_t` so you will have to cast the first one if you want a `size_t`.

Comment: These can be shortened still: `return std::distance(directory_iterator(path), {});` and `return std::count_if(directory_iterator(path), {}, std::filesystem::is_regular_file);`

Comment: Have you tested the `count_if` version? It won't compile. `is_regular_file` has three overloads.

Comment: [`return filesystem::remove_all(path)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/remove) technically meets the requirements.

Answer (score 9):

```
std::size_t number_of_files_in_directory(std::filesystem::path path)
{
    return (std::size_t)std::distance(std::filesystem::directory_iterator{path}, std::filesystem::directory_iterator{});
}
```

There is no function to find out how many files are in a directory, only functions to iterate over it. The OS only has functions like `readdir()`, `ftw()`, `FindFirstFileW()` so the standard cannot offer a better way.

(On the plus side that allows you to decide whether to, or how deep into, recurse into subdirectories)

Comment: @Boiethios yes it does: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator Also that is how the range based for works, so if your code works, then it must.

Comment: Is `std::ptrdiff_t` guaranteed to be implicitly convertible to `std::size_t`?

Comment: @clcto Hum, `std::ptrdiff_t` is signed; but a negative number of files makes little sense.

Comment: @Boiethios sure, but distance returns the `distance_type` which is `std::ptrdiff_t` for `directory_iterator`.

Comment: @clcto That's better to use an explicit cast IMO. Maybe you could edit the answer.

Comment: So we can use `begin()` and `end()` to get iterators from.. an iterator? This is kind of weird (I mean [the C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin), not your answer). In fact, to be honest, I'd be tempted to stick with `std::distance(directory_iterator{path}, directory_iterator{})`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're probably right, it certainly doesn't work on normal iterators (http://ideone.com/NhUiVS) so I'll change that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 17 you need to use the following namespace.

```
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

Then you could probably use a function like this one.

```
int Count() {
int count=0;
for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    count++;

}
    return count;
}
```